# Android Remote control app (on phone) for launch application from device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-tv, android-remoteview

How to get a list of applications that are installed on android tv and i want to display that list in an android phone application any one have idea how to get that?

I want to disply list of application which is install in android tv after sucessfull connection between android phone and tv.

I have no idea how to do that!

Comment: You can use an existing interface like `adb` or implement your own API which requires a self-developed app on both platform.